# Fetching Status Post in Facebook Using Facebook SDK iPhone (depending on the time it was posted)

Tags: ios, uitableview, facebook-graph-api

I want to display the status post of the user depending on its update time. I am now able to fetch the whole status post of the user when he login.

Exam of the fetched post showing 2 (two) status post:

[image]

I can also fetch the message (the status post) using this code:

```
[FBRequestConnection
 startWithGraphPath:@"me/statuses"
 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                     id result,
                     NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
     for (int y=0; y<=[result count]; y++) {
         NSLog(@"RESULTS: %@", result[@"data"][y][@"message"]);
     }
 }];
```

Result of the Code:

[image]

My question is, is it possible to get the specific message (status post) using the update_time?

its like select * from .... where update_time = "[the time]" in SQL. How to do it in iOS?

And display all the results in UITableview.

Comment: So you're essentially trying to get the user's most recent status?

Comment: no.. i want to get the specific post depending on the update_time of the post.. Example: the time i want to fetch is 2014-08-12T04:56:10+0000 to 2014-08-12T04:56:00+0000... the only post will be shown is in between that time

Comment: if i want to fetch the latest post.. i would just have to include limit (Example: me/statuses?limit=1)

Comment: I see what you mean. Posting an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When querying your Facebook statuses for a status posted at a particular time you're going to need to pass the since and until parameters to the endpoint @"/me/statuses".

Per the Facebook Graph API documentation:

> until : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the end of the range of time-based data.
>
> since : A Unix timestamp or strtotime data value that points to the start of the range of time-based data.

To give you an example, if you wanted to retrieve the all status messages since 8/9/2014 00:00:00 until 8/11/2014 00:00:00 you would use the following:

```
[FBRequestConnection
startWithGraphPath:@"/me/statuses?since=1407542400&until=1407715200"

 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                 id result,
                 NSError *error) {
 NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
 for (int y=0; y<=[result count]; y++) {
     NSLog(@"RESULTS: %@", result[@"data"][y][@"message"]);
 }
}];
```

[Click here to get unix timestamps](http://www.unixtimestamp.com/index.php)